A system of nonlinear Diophantine equations whose positive solutions are not coprime
Consider the following system of Diophantine equations:
$$v_1k_1=k_1^3-k_2^3+k_3^3 \\
v_2k_2=k_1^3+k_2^3-k_3^3 \\
v_3k_3=-k_1^3+k_2^3+k_3^3 \tag{1}$$
where $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are integer-valued variables.

Claim: If $v_1,v_2,v_3\ge2$ and $k_1,k_2,k_3 \ge 1$ is a solution of (1), then $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are not coprime.

Excluding the case $v_1=v_2=v_3=1$, the above states that for any positive solution of (1), $d=\text{gcd}(k_1,k_2,k_3)>1$. However, the above does not hold if some of $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are negative, for example, $$k_1=2,k_2= 7,k_3= 67 \\ v_1=150214, v_2= -42916, v_3=4494, $$ for which $d=1$. Moreover, $\text{gcd}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ or $\text{gcd}(\text{gcd}(k_1,v_1),\text{gcd}(k_2,v_2),\text{gcd}(k_3,v_3))$ can be 1 or greater, but $$\text{max}(\text{gcd}(k_1,v_1),\text{gcd}(k_2,v_2),\text{gcd}(k_3,v_3))>1. \tag{2}$$
I have numerically tested the above claim for all $k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \{1,\dots, 1000\}$ (all the 141730 integer solutions of (1) found in this range are provided in .txt and .xlsx files here; positive solutions are given in the first sheet of the .xlsx file).
Based on a numerical study (check the intersection of the three curves here; you can simply rotate the 3D figure), it seems that for any fixed positive integers $v_1,v_2,v_3$, system (1) has only one positive real solution $(k_1,k_2,k_3).$ Analyzing this solution (composed of the unique positive real roots of the three depressed cubic equations in (1)) may help to prove the above claim.
Remark 1. I came across this conjecture in my answer to this question, whose claim is a consequence of the above claim (c.f. (2)). Another consequence of the above claim is that $d^2| v_1,v_2,v_3 $ cannot hold, while there are examples in which $d| v_1,v_2,v_3 $, for example, $$k_1=81,k_2= 126,k_3= 135 \\ v_1=12240, v_2= 567, v_3=29106, $$ for which $d=9$. Such consequences may be used to disprove the above claim.
Remark 2. The claim for the following extension:
$$v_1k_1=k_1^n-k_2^n+k_3^n \\
v_2k_2=k_1^n+k_2^n-k_3^n \\
v_3k_3=-k_1^n+k_2^n+k_3^n \tag{3}$$
holds for $n=1,2,3,5$. However, it does not hold for $n=4$, which is only violated for $$k_1=13,k_2= 15,k_3= 16 \\ v_1=3344, v_2= 910, v_3=5475,$$ and its permutations, and for $n=6$, which is violated for many different solutions.
Remark 3. I found a property about cubs that depends on  positivity, which may be related to the above claim. For any positive number $n=x^3+y^3$ with $x,y\in \mathbb N$ and $n> 2$, there is $d$ with $\color{blue}{1<} n^{1/3}\le \color{blue}{d} \le 2^{2/3}n^{1/3} \color{blue}{< n}$ such that $d|n$, which follows from the identity $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$. However, for a positive number $n=x^3+y^3$ with $x,\color{blue}{-}y\in \mathbb N$, there is $\color{blue}{1 \le d} < n^{1/3}$ such that $d|n$ (see Theorem 2.1 in [4] and Theorem 3 in [5] for the characterization of numbers that can be expressed as the sum and difference of two cubs). Hence, there are $1<d_1<n_1$, $1<d_2<n_2$, $1<d_3<n_3$ such that $$d_1|n_1=v_1k_1+k_2^3=k_1^3+k_3^3 \\ d_2|n_2=v_2k_2+k_3^3=k_1^3+k_2^3 \\ d_3|n_3=v_3k_3+k_1^3=k_2^3+k_3^3$$
if $v_1,v_2,v_3 \ge 2$ and $k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \mathbb N.$
